# Create the content for Android USB printing

Tags: java, android, printing, usb

I'm new to Android, and I only started to learn for this App. I've reached the moment when I have in my Activity all data I need ( client and products ) and I want to print the invoice using Android USB printer. I'll show only relevant code because I managed to connect to USB printer. This is the method that works to print now.

```
String string = "\nThis \nis \nmy \nsample \ntext";
conn.bulkTransfer(endPoint, string.getBytes(), string.getBytes().length, 5000);
```

Everything goes well. My question is, how do I create the content now for the invoice? Should I create multiple strings ? Is there a way to create the invoice as plain string using tables and paragraphs, that can be converted to Byte? What I tried is creating a PDF using IText, it did create a test PDF, but I didn't managed to convert it to Byte correctly. Is there a plain Java way to create a PDF that can be converted to Byte ? This should be an app that my sales agents will use in their cars, so there is no possible way to use WIFI printing Apps. If possible, please suggest methods available for Android 4.0.4 because I already got 18 tablets. Thanks

Comment: "how do I create the content now for the invoice?" -- ask the manufacturer of your printer. Nobody else can tell you what the printer supports.

Comment: Being an amateur I assumed that if it can print a plain string from my code, it can print a not so complex table with seller, buyer and some products.

Comment: The printer is probably capable of this. However, the details of *how* to do this will be heavily dependent upon the printer itself, what protocols the printer manufacturer supports, etc. This is particularly true when you're slamming data right to the printer via a USB connection, rather than using some higher-level printing API (e.g., the printing support in Android 4.4+). So, contact the manufacturer.

Comment: From your knowledge, with Android 4.4+ , for example I can simply send a PDF to the USB printer ?

Comment: As with most operating systems, when you use a specific printing API, you neither know nor care how the printer is connected to the device (USB, WiFi, Bluetooth, tiny carrier pigeons, etc.). That being said, PDF is the format that Android uses with its printing API: http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

Comment: I understand. I'll take a look and try on my phone to see if this will work. Thanks.